# NextJS stuck at compiling

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg

All of my next apps are getting stuck at `event - compiled successfully` when I try and run them using `yarn dev`. Everything from existing apps I've used before to brand new apps I literally make just for trying this fresh.

I've tried deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, running `yarn` again, then running `yarn dev`. No dice. I also updated node js to latest and tried a few iterations of the above, including some with a 'yarn build` step to see if that did anything. No luck.

Assuming it's some kind of machine config that got messed up, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. Ideas?

Comment: same happens when i create an app with the `--use-npm` flag

Answer (score 1):

replace with it in package.json

“dev”: “next dev -p 1234",

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 1234",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 6000"
  },
```